# Layout виджета не изменяется

Tags: android, android-studio, android-widgets

Столкнулся с непонятной проблемой, порядок действий такой:

1. устанавливаю приложение
2. добавляю виджет на экран
3. редактирую виджет в Android Studio
4. запускаю версию программы с новым layout виджета (например, добавил `TextView`)

После этого виджет остается неизменным (именно layout, но код меняется). Удаление, добавление, создание новых экземпляров виджета - ничего не помогает. Спасает только удаление приложения и установка заново, но это очень неудобно. Собственно вопрос - это нормальное поведение приложения при разработке виджетов, или я что-то делаю не так?

Comment: Если вы используете вторую версию студии, то, возможно, дело именно в ней. Попробуйте на версии 1.5

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Это проблема **Instant Run** фьючи при сборки приложения. (Заливается только изменения, экономится время за счет отсутствия компиляции и сборки приложения, но есть проблема, что не все изменения отслеживаются, отсюда глюки)

Откройте настройки **Android Studio** и отключите **Instant Run** фьючу
**Settings - Build, Execution, Deployment - Instan Run** - Снимите все галки.

Comment: Если что то пошло не так и Instant Run не справляется, можно и не отключая его, принудительно полностью перезапустить, нажав *Rerun <app>*  (CTRL + F5), значок  - серый квадратик с зеленой стрелочкой загнутой вверх - в общем эта фича довольно удобная, чтоб просто от нее отказываться совсем.

Comment: Я как то заработался и забыл про фичу и потратил час ценного времени на бесполезный дебаг. Когда очухался - вырубил все нафиг. У меня привычка shift + f10 перезапускать...

Comment: Отлично, проблема решена, все работает как надо! Большое спасибо!